# How to show username using HTML and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

So, I am building a simple login page and I wanna show the username after you succesfully login to the page. But I am kind of confused how to do that in HTML. I saw lots of materials on ejs and angular and react and passport. But I am not using that. I am just using simple HTML,CSS and NodeJS to build this.
So, if someone can help me regarding this, I will be much obliged.

So my HTML page after I login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    Hi user. //want to show the username here
    <form name="logout" method="post" action='/logout'>
        <label class="logoutLblPos">
        <input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit2" value="log out">
        </label>
    </form>
</body>
```

and my code for successful login in server.js file:

```
app.post("/login", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",
    [email],
    async (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        try {
          if (result.length === 0 || !result) {
            res.json({ message: "Email has not been registered" });
          } else {
            bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].PASSWORD, (err, results) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.json({
                  message: "there has been some problem matching the password",
                });
              } else {
                if (results) {
                  //token creation
                  
                  const id = result[0].ID;
                  console.log(id)
                  const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
                  });

                  console.log("the token is " + token);

                  const cookieOptions = {
                    expires: new Date(
                      Date.now() +
                        process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                    ),
                    httpOnly: true,
                  };

                  res.cookie("myCookieJwt", token, cookieOptions)
                  res.status(200).redirect("/user");
                } else {
                  res.json({ message: "Please enter correct password" });
                }
              }
            });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some kind of library that make `POST` request to the endpoint. `JQuery Ajax` to rescue, you can use other libraries like `Axios` as well

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/login",
    data: "FORM DATA",//<---- Form Data (username,password)
    dataType: "text or JSON", //<-- Whichever you are using
    success: function(resultData) { $('#username').text(resultData.username); } //<-- I'm assuming username is coming in
});
```

you need to return `username` from node.js endpoint then You can set the text of `div` or any other HTML tag dynamically.

This example might need a tweaking as it might not work out of the box, but it will set you on correct path.

Comment: should I include this in my server.js file or in html file? never used ajax before so just asking.

Comment: Generally you make a separate file because this logic is for frontend (HTML) and you can use that file using `<script>` tags to import it into your HTML file